# How to change Company Name in App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have successfully uploaded an app to the App Store.

The app is showing like this:

[image: App in app store]

I want to change the Company Name text from `By eGInnovation` to `By eG Innovations`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

[Contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php). In the first question on the support page reads:

> **How can I update or change my iOS Developer Program account information?**
>   Please contact us for assistance with:
>
> - Address changes
> - Contact information updates
> - Company/Organization name updates or changes

Source: [Account Managment support](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new app on App Store Connect has a field for **Company Name**.

The "?" info text states:

> This will appear under your app name on your App Store product page. If you have a trade name, DBA, or fictitious business name, enter it here. **It can’t be changed later.**